# Insert Data Into Temp Table with Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have an existing query that outputs current data, and I would like to insert it into a Temp table, but am having some issues doing so. Would anybody have some insight on how to do this?

Here is an example

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT Received,
              Total,
              Answer,
              ( CASE
                  WHEN application LIKE '%STUFF%' THEN 'MORESTUFF'
                END ) AS application
       FROM   FirstTable
       WHERE  Recieved = 1
              AND application = 'MORESTUFF'
       GROUP  BY CASE
                   WHEN application LIKE '%STUFF%' THEN 'MORESTUFF'
                 END) data
WHERE  application LIKE isNull('%MORESTUFF%', '%')
```

This seems to output my data currently the way that i need it to, but I would like to pass it into a Temp Table. My problem is that I am pretty new to SQL Queries and have not been able to find a way to do so. Or if it is even possible. If it is not possible, is there a better way to get the data that i am looking for `WHERE application LIKE isNull('%MORESTUFF%','%')` into a temp table?

Comment: Into a `#temp` table that already exists or it would need to create a new one?

Comment: @MartinSmith - It would be a new one.

Comment: `LIKE ISNULL('%MORESTUFF%', '%')` will always be the same as `LIKE '%MORESTUFF%'`, won't it? Since '%MORESTUFF%' (the string literal) is never null?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM

  (SELECT
     Received,
     Total,
     Answer,
     (CASE WHEN application LIKE '%STUFF%' THEN 'MORESTUFF' END) AS application
   FROM
     FirstTable
   WHERE
     Recieved = 1 AND
     application = 'MORESTUFF'
   GROUP BY
     CASE WHEN application LIKE '%STUFF%' THEN 'MORESTUFF' END) data
WHERE
  application LIKE
    isNull(
      '%MORESTUFF%',
      '%')
```

Answer (score 175):

SQL Server R2 2008 needs the `AS` clause as follows:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM table1
) AS x
```

The query failed without the `AS x` at the end.

---

**EDIT**

It's also needed when using SS2016, had to add `as t` to the end.

```
 Select * into #result from (SELECT * FROM  #temp where [id] = @id) as t //<-- as t
```

Comment: Interesting. I just had the same issue. Adding "As [x]" at the end made everything work just fine. Why is this?

Comment: @godfathr it's because the from clause is using a derived table

Answer (score 45):

Fastest way to do this is using "SELECT INTO" command e.g.

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTableName
FROM....
```

This will create a new table, you don't have to create it in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to add columns to #TempTableName?

Comment: @FrenkyB yes, once table is created you can use ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN statement

Comment: Correct, I was getting temptable already created error, we dont need to create separately, it creates on the fly!decent!

Comment: As detailed in [@Shaun Luttin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29955231/3002584), the `FROM` clause needs an alias at its end, else an error happens.

Answer (score 18):

Personally, I needed a little hand holding figuring out how to use this and it is really, awesome.

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL) BEGIN DROP TABLE #TEMP END
        SELECT *
            INTO #TEMP
            FROM (
            The query you want to use many times
            ) AS X

SELECT * FROM #TEMP WHERE THIS = THAT
SELECT * FROM #TEMP WHERE THIS <> THAT
SELECT COL1,COL3 FROM #TEMP WHERE THIS > THAT

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: Extra `drop table` stuff is handy

Answer (score 11):

You can do that like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (colum1, column2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM OtherTable;
```

Just make sure the columns are matching, both in number as in datatype.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM 
(select * from tblorders where busidate ='2016-11-24' and locationID=12
) as X
```

Please use alias with x so it will not failed the script and result.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable 
FROM SampleTable
WHERE...

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. 
Try this way:

```
Create Global Temporary Table 
BossaDoSamba 
On Commit Preserve Rows 
As 
select ArtistName, sum(Songs) As NumberOfSongs 
 from Spotfy 
    where ArtistName = 'BossaDoSamba'
 group by ArtistName;
```

Answer (score 0):

use as at end of query

Select * into #temp
(select * from table1,table2) as temp_table